# Firebase Admin SDK Error Requested Project Not Found

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

### FIREBASE CONFIGURATION

I have those two service accounts in my Firebase Project

```
1) project-id@appspot.gserviceaccount.com
2) firebase-adminsdk-8myok@project-id.iam.gserviceaccount.com
```

In the IAM configuration, the first account has the role "Editor", and the second has:

```
1) Administrator Service Agent for the Administrator SDK
2) Service account token creator
3) Storage Manager
```

The code of my cloud functions is just:

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
const sizeOf = require("image-size");
const url = require("url");
const https = require("https");

// Initialize App
admin.initializeApp({
  databaseURL: "https://project-id.firebaseio.com",
  storageBucket: "project-id.appspot.com",
});

// Create Storage
const storage = admin.storage();

// Create Firestore
const firestore = admin.firestore();

// Validate image dimensions
exports.validateImageDimensions = functions
  .region("us-central1")
  // Increased memory, decreased timeout (compared to defaults)
  .runWith({ memory: "2GB", timeoutSeconds: 120 })
  .https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
    // Get the image's owner
    const owner = context.auth.token.uid;

    // Get the image's info
    const { id, description, location, tags, time } = data;

    // Get the photos' bucket
    const bucket = storage.bucket("photos");
    ...
```

And my service account is just the .json generated on the Firebase Console:

```
Project Configuration > Service Accounts > Firebase Admin SDK -> Generate Private Key
```

### ERROR

When calling the function I get this error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 404,
    "message": "The requested project was not found.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "The requested project was not found.",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "notFound"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: just to confirm, you are getting this error with the first or the second service account?

Comment: First. Know I have give it the "Editor" role but still failing. The editor role is the defaut one that is given when this service account is created by google cloud. (I deleted it by mistake in the past)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are using the service account without roles, I suggest you take a look at this [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup#initialize-sdk%20%5B).

Also, this is a common issue you can check another threads [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=404%20service%20account) and try with some workaround suggested.

Just as a kind reminder, I suggest you check if the URL declared https://project-id.firebaseio.com wast set without mistakes, when I try to enter to  URL I'm getting the message: "not found".

If this behavior persists I think you could try to report your use as is recommended [here](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker)

Comment: Have done everething but still having the same error

Comment: I think you are followin this document in order to install your database  https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/start, however when I try to enter to the URL https://project-id.firebaseio.com I receive the message: "not found", could you confirm with me the database is available?